# Why the document will be checked out by default when uploading it while having a custom content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, versioning, check-out

I did the following:-

1. I created a new modern SharePoint page >> inside it i added a Button web part, as follow:-

[image]

2. The url for the button refers to the upload dialog for a document library, as follow @ `/sites/POS-DocumentApprovalProcess/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=%7b71b0e1f5-c427-44f8-9147-cb24d9df8dd8%7d`
3. Now I click on the above Button >> Upload the document, as follow:-

[image]

4. Then i will be redirected to the edit properties form (since the document library has a custom content type with custom columns), as follow:-

[image]

5. After that i populated the required properties inside the edit form >> click on Save.

But the issue is that the uploaded document will be checked-out by default as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice why this is happening? why the document will be checked-out after been uploaded?

I checked the versioning settings for the document library and i have the following, so the document should not be checked-out by default when been uploaded and edited !!!:-

[image]

Comment: Do you have any required fields in your custom content type?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes i have a field that is required, but when i enter the edit form i added the field and save the form..but the file will still be checked-out!!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps given by you, tried the same from my end and observed the same behavior in my SharePoint Online tenant.

I think this is some kind of bug or known issue (See below references).

**My observations**:

1. If custom content type has any **required** custom site columns then document is getting checked out automatically.
2. If custom content type does not have any custom site column or it does not have any **required** custom site columns then document is not getting checked out.

**Suggestion**: Create [Online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products) ticket with Microsoft.

**References**:

1. [How to Ensure that Users are Prompted for Document Metadata in Office 365 and SharePoint 2016](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3045118/how-to-ensure-that-users-are-prompted-for-document-metadata-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-2016.html) - See **Bonus Tip** section.
2. [Don't Mess with Default Content Types in SharePoint](https://lydonsolutions.com/2019/09/06/default-content-types-in-sharepoint/) - See **So what’s the big deal?** section

Comment: but the strange thing is that if i use the New button inside the list view (not using the button inside the modern page) i will not get any issues even if i have required fields...

Comment: True, I have observed that too in my SharePoint site.

Comment: the problem i am in the middle of a project and stuck with this weird bug :(